# Get list of ip adresses in playbook

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2, glusterfs

I'm new to Ansible and couldn't figure out how to achieve this from the documentation:
I have an inventory file like this:

```
example_site:
  children:
    ...
    example_hosts:
      hosts:
        h1:
          ansible_host: "192.168.0.1"
        h2:
          ansible_host: "192.168.0.2"
```

Now I want to start a Gluster cluster there in a playbook:

```
  tasks:
    - name: Create a trusted storage pool
      become: yes
      gluster.gluster.gluster_peer:
        state: present
        nodes:
          - "192.168.0.1"
          - "192.168.0.2"
```

Is there a way to not hardcode this list of ip addresses? I tried `node: groups['example_hosts']`, but that did not work.

How can I get a list of ip addresses from the inventory?

Comment: Ref: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/intro_inventory.html#group-variables

Comment: Thank you for the reference, but I don't want to write all ip addresses a second time in variables, but directly use the ip addresses defined in the hosts part of the inventory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP addresses of hosts defined in your inventory can be accessed with the `ansible_host` variable, i.e. `hostvars['h1']['ansible_host']` => "192.168.0.1". Since you need the IP address of the hosts in that group as an array, we can iterate over the hosts in `group['example_hosts']`, which is a list `["h1", "h2"]` as well.

In the below example, we create another variable with the list of IP address of hosts in `example_hosts` group:

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        cluster_hosts: "{{ cluster_hosts|default([]) + [ hostvars[item]['ansible_host'] ] }}"
      loop: "{{ groups['example_hosts'] }}"
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        var: cluster_hosts
```

This gives the list of IP addresses in `cluster_hosts`:

```
    "cluster_hosts": [
        "192.168.0.1",
        "192.168.0.2"
    ]
```

This variable can be passed to the `nodes` parameter of the `gluster_peer` module:

```yaml
        nodes: "{{ cluster_hosts }}"
```